# Why won't this c.move function work?

Tags: python, tkinter, pong

So I'm creating a very basic pong game in python, as one of my first independant projects, just to see what I know and to test myself. Tell me, why won't the Tkinter module work with this code?

```
HEIGHT=500
WIDTH=800
window=Tk()
window.title('PONG!')
c=Canvas(window,width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT,bg='black')
c.pack()

def pongstick():
    c.create_polygon(20,30, 30,30, 30,100, 20,100, fill='white')

pong1=pongstick()
MID_X = WIDTH/2
MID_Y=HEIGHT/2
c.move(pong1, MID_X, MID_Y)
```

This returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jackstrange/Documents/Untitled.py", line 16, in <module>
    c.move(pong1, MID_X, MID_Y)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2430, in move
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".4385131376 move tagOrId xAmount yAmount"
```

I could just be being completely stupid and forgetting something very obvious, but I don't know why this won't work!

Comment: You're missing enough code to make this a [mcve]. Please [edit] your question and provide a MCVE.

Comment: Your `pongstick` does **not returning anything**.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't return the ID. Try this:

```
def pongstick():
    return c.create_polygon(20,30, 30,30, 30,100, 20,100, fill='white')
```

Comment: Thank you! I never really understood what the return function did, since it was really poorly explained in class. If you wouldn't mind, explain what that exactly did?

Comment: The 'create_polygon' function makes a polygon and then returns the ID of the polygon it created. You need that ID in order to tell the canvas what to move. The return statement passes the ID along so that it's saved into the 'pong1' variable. Without it, python automatically returns a `None`, which the canvas widget interpreted as no input, which prompted the error. The error message is a bit unclear, but it boils down to "you didn't tell me what to move".